# Jenkins pipeline job not start build while trigger from 'Bitbucket server webhook to jenkins'

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

Jenkins simple pipeline project not start build while trigger from 'Bitbucket server webhook to jenkins' Hook from bitbucket respository.

The same thing working perfectly with Freestyle job, but only pipeline job not start building. So bitbucket webhook configuration is proper.
[bitbucket plugin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0e6U.jpg)

Below is my pipeline job configuration.
[Jenkins pipeline job triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfsbG.jpg)

And the simple pipeline script which I'm using.
[Jenkins pipeline job script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqjPL.jpg)

Comment: Did you configure the hook on the Bitbucket side aswell? Go to your Bitbucket Server repo --> Repository Settings --> Hooks --> Configure your 'Bitbucket Server Webhook to Jenkins Plugin'

Comment: Yes @Max, I did, and that's why it working fine in Freestyle project. You can check first image in my question 'bitbucket plugin configuration'.

Comment: Oh I missed that! What I have successfully used is this plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213179/parameterized-builds-for-jenkins?hosting=server&tab=overview

Comment: Thanks, @Max I really appreciate your response, but the thing is I must configure with the plugin We already have. So it's good If one can help me to solve the existing part.

Comment: Hi @ManishJain! Can you give an update how you solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @handras, Yes we did achieve that, but it's hard for me to recall the same cause quite a long time has passed. But I shall check that and revert to you when get time. Sorry for unable to give you immediate help.